# React Native FlatList, Images are flickering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

So I have a FlatList

```
<FlatList
  overScrollMode='never'
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={feedContent}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  ListHeaderComponent={!isDiscovery && renderHeader()}
  ListEmptyComponent={renderEmptyState()}
  refreshing={refreshing}
  onRefresh={onRefresh}
  renderItem={renderItem}
/>
```

And I am calling renderItem in it, renderItem then returns a JSX element called Item, it contains an Image component from expo-image, that has integrated caching.

```js
const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return <Item item={item} />;
};

const Item: React.FC<{ item: Item }> = React.memo(
  ({ item }: { item: Item }) => {
    const [isImage2Active, setIsImage2Active] = useState(false);

   
        const image1Url = useMemo(() =>, item.picture.url1, []);
        const image2Url = useMemo(() =>, item.picture.url2, []);


        const handleImagePress = useCallback(() => {
            setIsImage2Active(!isImage2Active);
        }, [isImage2Active]);


return(
<>
        <Image
          source={isImage2Active ? item.picture1 : image2Url}
          style={{ width: 40, height: 40, borderRadius: 20, marginRight: 10 }}
        />
<Button onPress={handleImagePress} />
      </>)
    );
  }
);
```

The issue I am having here is, that the image flickers on every reload so I assume it is not cached. When I put the Image inside of renderItem everything works fine, but in renderItem I cannot use React Hooks, which I need in this case, so I have to use another functional component to return the Image. But as already mentioned when I return it through the Item component, on every reload the Image flickers.

Tried returning it directly in renderItem={(item) => {} but it did not help, and also tried to use React.memo and useMemo hooks.

Comment: You can add isImage2Active array  to  feedContent instead of creating an useState for each listigem.

Comment: Similar to my sample https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/toggle-boolean-array
Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: @MichaelBahl,  I am sorry, I noticed that I did not provide the complete code. There is some stateful logic, and the image url switches when the button is pressed, that is why I need state in this component, and I cannot useState in renderItem you know

Comment: You should amend the state of the data property and note the state of the listitem.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@gabrielsideprojects/toggle-boolean-array) using the <Image/> from 'react-native' and I could not reproduce it, I used the Image from 'react-native' and it worked pretty well, it did not blink. Can you try to use the Image from react and see if it blinks? I think that the problem may be the expo-image.